# IF statement in Google Sheet QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a Google Sheet that sucks in values from Analytics and allows a user to go in, select various landing pages from a dropdown list, and source of traffic and see various stats relating to that source/landing page.

It's all working apart from I want to have a 'all' selection in the sources dropdown.

A simplified version of the formula I am using to generate the results is:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Sheet1'!$A$16:$M$6969,"select sum(E) where (A) contains '" & $B$4 & "' AND B = " & MONTH(B$6) & " AND C = " & YEAR(B$6) & " AND D = '" & $B$3 & "' label sum(E) ''",1),0)
```

`A` is the landing page code, i.e. `landing-page`

`B` and `C` just get a date from a header row

`D` is the one I am struggling with. At the moment `B3` is a dropdown containing `cpc`, `organic`, `direct`, `all`. If I select anything but `all` it works, but I need to write some sort of condition so if `all` is selected then `AND D = '" & $B$3 & "'` isn't used.

I don't seem to be able to put an IF statement within a QUERY so unsure how to proceed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to generate the Query dynamically, especially with multiple filter conditions it is usually easier to replace the filter condition with `1=1`.
This eliminates possible problems of trailing `AND` and `OR` clauses.

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Sheet1'!$A$16:$M$6969,
               "select sum(E) 
                where (A) contains '" & $B$4 & "' 
                      AND B = " & MONTH(B$6) & " 
                      AND C = " & YEAR(B$6) & " 
                      AND " & IF($B$3="all", "1=1", "D = '" & $B$3 &"'")& "      
                label sum(E) ''",1),0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's why I love SO! All makes sense now :)